# (x86-64) GNU Assembly macro

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I just started learning about assembly but I got confused with the .macro function. I have been able to find examples which are used to add some numbers in a range but none with strings. If I wanted to write a macro to repeat 3 lines of text, how would the code look like?

#edit

I talked with my mentor and he provided an example that I used to write the assembly code below:

```
.altmacro

.macro .printPlusPlus a
.print "\a"
.endm


.printPlusPlus <Hello, programmers!!>
.printPlusPlus <Welcome to the world of,>
.printPlusPlus <Linux assembly programing!!>
```

Comment: What do you mean repeat 3 lines of text? Could you provide an example

Comment: It's for an assignment and I have to print "Hello, programmers! Welcome to the world of, Linux assembly programming!" using a gnu macro

Answer (score 1):

GAS has a [`.rept`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_node/as_114.html#SEC116) macro that lets you repeat some code *n* times. Furthermore, the very first example in the [`.macro`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_node/as_107.html#SEC109) page basically gives you another way to make a `.repeat times,another_macro` macro that can call it second argument `times` times.

I've basically never really used GAS, the code below is just a PoC.

It shows how you can use `.rept`, the `.repeat` macro said above and two macros for `sys_write` and `sys_exit`.
All in all, I don't like it (I'm sure there are better ways to write the macros) but it's commented and can serve as an answer.

```
#
# Constants
#
SYS_WRITE=1
SYS_EXIT=60

STDOUT=1

#
#This macro is similar to .rept but it takes the body to repeat as an argument
#This argument should be a name denoting a macro with no arguments
# 
.macro  repeat times, body
    #Call the macro
    \body
    
    #Recurse if the next value of times is not 0
    .if \times-1
        repeat     "(\times-1)",\body
    .endif
.endm


#
#This macro print the string text given as its argument
#This work by switching to the data section, defining a local label 0 before the string and 
#  a local label 1 after the string (so we can get the string length as the difference), switching
#  back to the text section and inserting a system call for SYS_WRITE
#
.macro print text
    #Write the string in the data section and sorround it with two labels
    .section .data
    0:
    .string "\text"
    1:
    
    #Go back to the text section and invoke the system call
    .section .text
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %eax
    mov $STDOUT, %edi
    lea 0b(%rip), %rsi
    mov $(1b-0b-1), %edx        #The -1 is because GAS always add a null-term
    syscall
.endm

#
#This is a simple macro to call SYS_EXIT returning the optional argument ret
#
.macro exit ret=0
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    mov $\ret, %edi
    syscall
.endm

#
#Since the repeat macro requires a 0-arity macro name, we need a wrapper macro for print
#  with its string argument
#
.macro print_hello
    print "Hello, programmers! Welcome to the world of, Linux assembly programming!\n"
.endm



#
# CODE
#

.global _start
.section .text

_start:
    #Use our repeat macro
    repeat 3,print_hello 
    
    #Use GAS .rept
    .rept 3
        print "Hello scripters! This is not like assembly at all!\n"
    .endr
    
    #Exit
    exit
```

Comment: I tried running your code but I got "stack.c: Assembler messages:
stack.c:83: Error: no such instruction: `share'
stack.c:84: Error: no such instruction: `edit' "

Comment: `as thecode.S -o thecode.o` works on my machine. You seem to be inlining since there's no `stack` or `share` anywhere in my code.